# Text event in wxpython

Tags: python, python-2.7, event-handling, wxpython

I am having trouble in wxpython. I would like to know how to produce text on a dialog that *looks* like static text but when you click on it, it runs an event. Does anybody have any idea how I could do such a thing?

Comment: use the `wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN` handler ...

Comment: why do you want to do that? i mean, that sounds confusing as a user, to have something i don't expect to be responsive to respond to clicks. if this is for an easter egg or something, ok, but otherwise, you want the static text to _look_ clickable...

Comment: In short, what I am trying to do is make a map-editor for my pygame game. There will be configurable actions which might have a description such as:
"**A unit** will go to **A point**"
You should be able to click on the one of those in bold and change it to the character and point of your choice.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the mouse click events, like wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN or wx.EVT_LEFT_UP along with the static text widget's HitTest method. So in your mouse event handler, you would want to call HitTest and use it to determine if you clicked within the static widget. See the following documentation for additional information:

- http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/HitTest.enumeration.html